# Sens de « foncer » dans « J'imagine » de Annie Villeneuve

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, paroles-de-chanson

J'ai du mal à saisir l'acception du verbe **foncer** dans les paroles de [cette chanson](http://www.metrolyrics.com/jimagine-lyrics-annie-villeneuve.html), car il y en a [plusieurs tout à fait différentes](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/foncer/34442?q=foncer#34389). Comment la déduire ou inférer ?

> je fonce alors je vie

Je suis conscient de la version anglaise de cette chanson, mais j'opte pour ne pas m'y référer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans la phrase que tu cites :

> je fonce alors je vis<sup>1</sup>

Le verbe *foncer* est employé de façon intransitive (il n'a pas de complément d'objet direct). La bonne définition est sur [cette page](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/foncer/34443?q=foncer#34390).
Et vu le contexte c'est la dernière définition qu'il faut considérer :

> Aller de l'avant sans hésiter, être très dynamique

<sup>1. Je corrige l'orthographe erronée des paroles sur le site vers lequel tu as fait le lien.</sup>